# Building a function that uses dictionaries to store values that modify class attributes

Tags: python, oop, dictionary

In my text-based RPG, I have a player class with various attributes, one of which being `self.abilities`, which is a list storing static abilities.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.strength = 5
        ...
        self.abilities = []
        ...
```

`self.strength` is an example of another player value.

In this program, I have another class named `Ability`, which stores information that affects base player values like `self.strength`. It has a class method that produces abilities to be added to the player class.

```
class Ability(object):
    # `ability_names` lists ALL of the base player values that can be 
    # modified by an ability. 
    ability_names = ['strength', 'intelligence', 'dexterity', 'defense',
    'endurance', 'block', 'faith', 'sorcery', 'speech', 'luck', 'health',
    'stamina', 'mana', 'equip load']

    def __init__(self, name, buff, descripton):
        self.name = name
        self.buff = buff
        self.descripton = descripton

    @classmethod
    def generate(cls, player):
        name = choice(cls.ability_names) + ' ' + 'buff'
        buff_amt =  randint(1, player.level * 3)
        buff = {name: buff_amt}
        description = 'This ability applies a buff of {} to your {} attribute'.format(buff_amt, name)
        return cls(name, buff, description)
```

For the sake of example, lets say we append an `Ability` instance to the player's `self.abilities` list value with the `Ability.generate()` method and declare the `self.buff` value equaling `{'strength': 3}`. If this is the case, how can I go about writing a function that pulls the information from the `Ability` instance's `self.buff` dictionary and apply those values to the `Player` class' attributes, or rather add `3` to the player's `strength`?

Comment: Any reason you wish to use a list for the abilities and not a dictionary?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Do all the names in the `ability_names` list match with the name of a member variable in `Player`?  What do you mean by "apply those values" - apply them how?  By "or rather add" in the last sentence, do you mean "for example add"?  You ask how you should go about writing a particular function, but have you tried to write it, and if so what difficulty did you have?